# Как объеденить scss файлы в один webpack

Tags: webpack

Возникла задача объединить scss файлы в один.Без компиляции в css. Как это можно сделать в Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

В общем так и не понял как сделать эту простую задачу через webpack, оказалось даже проще в gulp написать задание.

Используя  [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat)

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/file1.scss',
                   './src/file2.scss',
                   './src/file3.scss'])
    .pipe(concat('./src/file1_file2_file3.scss'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```